# How to check email validation using regex in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a registration form for my Django project. I want to check if the user's email address is correct. I used built-in email validator, but it just check the domain. I need to prevent user to enter emails like this: john#doe@gmail.com etc.
here is my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user     = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name     = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    email    = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, validators=[validate_email])
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    created  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id       = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2']
        labels = {'first_name':'Name',}
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def createProfile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        user    = instance
        profile = Profile.objects.create(
            user     = user,
            username = user.username,
            email    = user.email,
            name     = user.first_name,
        )
```

and views.py for registration

```
def registerUser(request):
    page = 'register'
    form = CustomUserCreationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.username = user.username.lower()
            user.save()

            messages.success(request, 'User Account Was Created!')
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('profile')

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'An error has accurred during registration!')

    context = {'page' : page, 'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'users/login-register.html', context)
```

Comment: While gmail don't allow '#' in the address, some providers might allow it. To validate the structure of an email address is valid you can use this regex pattern: `pattern = r'^[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+$'`. You with that you can extract the part before the domain and check if it contains illegal characters in case it's Gmail or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re
import re
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# email validator
def validate_email(email):
    regex = r'^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$'
    return re.match(regex, email) is not None

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2']
        labels = {'first_name': 'Name'}

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if not validate_email(email):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid email format. Please enter a valid email address.")
        return email
```